# Ionic 4 - InAppBrowser plugin causes error on ios: exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, ionic4, inappbrowser, capacitor

I used cordova-plugin-inappbrowser in my ionic project. When i run the app on android, inappbrowser works just fine, it can be opened and closed. The problem is that when i run the app on ios (both on simulator and a real device) it gives me the error:

> exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

and the app crashes. I also removed the options but no luck.
Here is the code block i used:

```
openLoginBrowser() {
    const browser = this.inapp.create('...URL_HERE...', '_blank', {
      zoom: 'no',
      hideurlbar: 'yes'
    });
    browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(response => {
      ...
    });
  }
```

package.json :

```
...  
"@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",  
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.20.0",  
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",  
"@capacitor/cli": "^1.2.1",  
"@capacitor/android": "^1.2.0",
"@capacitor/core": "^1.2.1",
"@capacitor/ios": "^1.3.0",
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Latest `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` doesn't work with Capacitor because it relies in having `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` or `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` installed, and both of them are incompatible with Capacitor.

The plugin needs to be updated to remove those checks.

Comment: i think my previous search terms were not enough. i just noticed this topic (your fix) on capacitor github page: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2315. the error occures at the same point with same code. i will try to update capacitor related packages as soon as i can and share the results.

Comment: updated all capacitor packages to v1.5.0. the problem has been partially solved. now the inappbrowser can be opened but "sometimes" view doesn't refresh. the events are triggered, but the only thing i can see is the loading icon and "done" button.